# VBA - Conditional Formatting with dynamic formulas using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, conditional-formatting

I am making a project planning worksheet and writing a function to add a team member that inserts a number of grouped cells for summing up hours per week.

The new cells should have a conditional format to show when the total actual hours worked (shown in blue) exceed the planned hours worked (column M).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcbMz.png)

[Manage Rules Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75R6U.png)

I am having some trouble using the range that I define in Formula1:
When I run the program, it does define the conditional format, but the formula shown in "manage rules" shows the name of the range, not the cells I am trying to format.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

I have defined the range of cells to be formatted, but it doesn't seem to translate to actual cell selections when using MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=sum(MyRange)>FmtHrs"

> 

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim iCol As Long
Dim WeekCount As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim FmtRow As Long

Set ws = Sheet1




'This sections adds new staff member info'


'This sections adds weeks for new staff memeber'

WeekCount = Range("B3").Value  'number of columns to add (weeks of project in B3)'
LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'position of new columns at last column with data'
Columns(LastCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

For i = 1 To WeekCount  'inserts columns for each week of project'
    Columns(LastCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next i

'insterns column for new staff and adds labels'
LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + WeekCount + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, LastCol).Value = "Role"
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, LastCol).Value = "Name"
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, LastCol).Value = "Rate"

'Groups New Columns
LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(1, LastCol - WeekCount), Cells(1, LastCol - 1)).Columns.Group
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1 'collapses all groups

'Adds Conditional Formats to New Rows
RowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
FmtRow = RowCount
Dim FmtHrs As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim condition1 As FormatCondition



For i = RowCount - 1 To 6 Step -1
FmtHrs = ActiveSheet.Cells(FmtRow, LastCol)
Set MyRange = Range(Cells(FmtRow, LastCol - WeekCount), Cells(FmtRow, LastCol - 1))
    
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=sum(MyRange)>FmtHrs"
    MyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(128, 100, 250)

FmtRow = FmtRow - 1
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `"=sum(MyRange)>FmtHrs"` as formula to the conditional formatting. In Excel, `MyRange` has no meaning, that's a VBA variable. What you want is to write the range address into the formula.

An advice: don't write the formula directly, always use an intermediate variable, that makes it much easier to check if something does not work as expected

```
Dim formula As String
formula = "=sum(" & MyRange.Address & ")>FmtHrs"
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work, but also needed to write the range FmtHrs adress as well. 
  formula = "=sum(" & MyRange.Address & ")> sum(" & FmtHrs.Address & ")"